# RealityKit – macOS Photogrammetry app's Error

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, realitykit, photogrammetry

For the past few days I've tried creating a photogrammetry command line app in Xcode. But I keep getting an error when I try to run the code.

The error I get is the following:

`[Photogrammetry] queueNextProcessingBatchIfNeeded(): Already running a job... not starting new one.`

I've searched on Google but I can't find anyone who has experienced the same issue.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import Foundation
import RealityKit

let inputFolderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/username/Desktop/AirForce", isDirectory: true)
let session = try! PhotogrammetrySession(input: inputFolderUrl, configuration: PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration())

try! session.process(requests: [.modelFile(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/username/Desktop/MyModel.usdz"), detail: .preview)])
```

**My system:**
MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559)
Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)

Comment: Hey @Andy Jazz! 
No, I don’t use the ```ArgumentParser ``` framework. Should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Use my code. It works. If you need more details on photogrammetry, read my [Medium post](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-photogrammetry-77659381af50).

```
import Cocoa
import RealityKit

struct Photogrammetry {

    typealias Config = PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration
    typealias Request = PhotogrammetrySession.Request
    var inputFolder = "/Users/swift/Desktop/WildBoar"
    var outputFile = "/Users/swift/Desktop/wildBoar.usdz"
    var detail: Request.Detail = .medium

    fileprivate func running() {
        var config = PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration()
        config.featureSensitivity = .normal
        config.isObjectMaskingEnabled = true
        config.sampleOrdering = .unordered

        let inputFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputFolder, 
                                     isDirectory: true)

        var optionalSession: PhotogrammetrySession? = nil

        do {
            optionalSession = try PhotogrammetrySession(
                                             input: inputFolderURL,
                                     configuration: config)        
        } catch {
            print("ERROR")
            Foundation.exit(1)
        }

        guard let session = optionalSession 
        else { Foundation.exit(1) }

        withExtendedLifetime(session) {
            do {
                let request = PhotogrammetrySession.Request
                   .modelFile(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFile),
                           detail: detail)
                try session.process(requests: [request])
                RunLoop.main.run()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR")
                Foundation.exit(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that inputFolder must have *.HEIC depth.TIF and gravity.TXT files right? I'm looking for a way to produce 3D models without requiring that *.HEIC depth.TIF and gravity.TXT files... here's a solution from Apple guy but I got nothing! https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698334

Comment: My solution is written for macOS 12.0+, and it does not require `depth` data and `gravity` data (they are optional). I haven’t tried the solution for iOS 17 yet, have no enough time for that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem I solved it by adding a single line.
RunLoop.main.run()

```
import Foundation
import RealityKit

let inputFolderURL =  URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/saibalaji/Desktop/ObjectCapture/ObjectCapture/Images/camera",isDirectory: true)
let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/saibalaji/Desktop/ObjectCapture/ObjectCapture/Camera.usdz")

let session = try! PhotogrammetrySession(input: inputFolderURL, configuration: PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration())
let request = PhotogrammetrySession.Request.modelFile(url: outputURL, detail: .medium)
try!  session.process(requests: [request])
        RunLoop.main.run()
```